# How to fill NSArray in compile time?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

In Objective-C, how to do something like is

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

in pure C?

I need to fill NSArray with NSStrings with the smallest overhead (code and/or runtime) as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible to create an array like you're doing at compile time. That's because it's not a "compile time constant." Instead, you can do something like:

```
static NSArray *tArray = nil;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    tArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", nil];
}
```

If it's truly important that you have this precompiled, then I guess you could create a test project, create the array (or whatever object) you need, fill it, then serialize it using NSKeyedArchiver (which will save it to a file), and then include that file in your app. You will then need to use NSKeyedUnarchiver to unarchive the object for use. I'm not sure what the performance difference is between these two approaches. One advantage to this method is that you don't have a big block of code if you need to initialize an array that includes a lot of objects.

Comment: It is not important to have it precompiled, so your solution works perfectly for me. Thanks!

Comment: This creates the array each time `viewDidLoad` executes, a `nil` test would be good.

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:str1,str2,  nil];
```

Comment: Worth noting that `str1, str2...` can be NSString literals like `@"some string"`, in the same way as they would be for a C array initialiser. I *think* such strings will be inited at compile time in the image. Don't think you can init the array itself other than at runtime, though, at least not without some ugly serialisation hack.

Comment: This does not work for me. I did
    NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"foo", @"bar", @"baz", nil];
and the compiler says "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant". I need to share the array among several routines in a module, so I want the array to be declared and filled outside any routine...

Comment: -1 As MoreFamed pointed out, this will absolutely not work the way he needs. Your code *would* work if he only needed to access `array` in a single method, but he needs access to it throughout his class.

Answer (score -2):

As far as i understand you need a one-dimentional array
You can use class methods of [NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html).. For instance

```
NSString *yourString;
NSArray  *yourArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:yourString, nil];
```

If you need more, please give some more detail about your issue

Comment: -1 Your answer has the same issue as @sheraza's. It's not going to provide access to the array across the entire class.

Answer (score -3):

Simple as that: `NSArray<NSString*> *stringsArray = @[@"Str1", @"Str2", @"Str3", ...];` Modern ObjectiveC allows generics and literal arrays.

If you want shorter code, then `NSArray *stringsArray = @[@"Str1", @"Str2", @"Str3", ...];`, as the generics are optional and help only when accessing the array elements, thus you can later in the code cast back to the templatized array.

Comment: I can't compile it as constant/static.

Comment: Yes, it won't work as that is a runtime executed construction.