# Immutable Array/Dictionary Initialization

Tags: ios, nsarray

If I initialize an `NSArray` as follows:

```
- (void) myMethod
{
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A","B","C",nil];
    // DO SOME STUFF HERE
    return;
}
```

Is this immutable array initialized at compile time or at run time?  Same with `NSDictionary`. I'm thinking it must be at compile time but just wondering.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050855/how-to-fill-nsarray-in-compile-time

Comment: All the object are initialized at run time except the static and macros.

Answer (score 3):

No… It would not be created in compile time… It would be created in runtime when the Method is being called.
 By Immutability, it means that You cannot edit size of the array after once initializing it.

refer to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ObjectMutability/ObjectMutability.html) Link for more info about Object Mutability… Let me know if more info needed.. :)

Answer (score 0):

**No**, Method call `arrayWithObjects:` is not possible at compile time. During compilation, it just check that syntax, unless that variable would be constants or statics. Macros and constants are initialized at compile time. See this example below.

You could initialize directly, if the size is known as below(same example also posted by @simalone)

```
int num[5] = {2,8,7,6,0};
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code is what you want?

```
static NSString *strArray[] = {@"A", @"B", @"C"};
```

To use it with index like this: `stringArray[index]`;